# Histogram Equalization based on HSI model

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am using Python 2.7 on Debian Linux along with matplotlib, Numpy and Scipy and PIL. 
I am able to generate a histogram for the H S and I parameters of an image using the code mentioned. I intend to apply histogram equalization on the H S and I histograms and then convert it back to a resultant image so that I can compare the changes. Can somebody help me with the necessary code for histogram equalization and converting back the equalized histogram to an image.

```
import scipy
from scipy import ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc
import scipy.misc

img = scipy.misc.imread("/home/subhradeep/Desktop/testc.jpg")
array=np.asarray(img)
arr=(array.astype(float))/255.0
img_hsv = colors.rgb_to_hsv(arr[...,:3])

lu1=img_hsv[...,0].flatten()
plt.subplot(1,3,1)
plt.hist(lu1*360,bins=360,range=(0.0,360.0),histtype='stepfilled', color='r', label='Hue')
plt.title("Hue")
plt.xlabel("Value")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.legend()

lu2=img_hsv[...,1].flatten()
plt.subplot(1,3,2)                  
plt.hist(lu2,bins=100,range=(0.0,1.0),histtype='stepfilled', color='g', label='Saturation')
plt.title("Saturation")   
plt.xlabel("Value")    
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.legend()

lu3=img_hsv[...,2].flatten()
plt.subplot(1,3,3)                  
plt.hist(lu3*255,bins=256,range=(0.0,255.0),histtype='stepfilled', color='b', label='Intesity')
plt.title("Intensity")   
plt.xlabel("Value")    
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I need to implement the eq (4) in python

[image: Algorithm Description]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware, you need only apply the histogram equalisation to the value component of the HSV transform to equalise the image:

```
def histeq(im,nbr_bins=256):
    """  Histogram equalization of a grayscale image. 
         From http://programmingcomputervision.com/"""

    # get image histogram
    imhist,bins = np.histogram(im.flatten(),nbr_bins,normed=True)
    cdf = imhist.cumsum() # cumulative distribution function
    cdf = 1 * cdf / cdf[-1] # normalize (value component max is 1.0)

    # use linear interpolation of cdf to find new pixel values
    im2 = np.interp(im.flatten(),bins[:-1],cdf)

    return im2.reshape(im.shape), cdf

#equalise the intensity component
img_hsv[:,:,2], cdf = histeq(img_hsv[:,:,2])

#then convert back to RGB space
img_eq = colors.hsv_to_rgb(img_hsv)
```

Underexposed input image:

[image: Underexposed image]

Histogram equalised output image:

[image: Equalised image]

You can, of course, apply the above to each channel of the HSV transform if you wish to see what the output would look like.  I am not sure what you would achieve by doing that though.

Comment: Hey i just did as you described but i want to use the same technique for the saturation parameter also as well as calculate the average value of the histogram how do I go about that?

Comment: Actually I'm performing a special type of histogram equalization on coloured images thats called HE-VED or histogram equalization with variable enhancement degree in which u have a parameter a(alpha) for the saturation parameter

for alpha = 1 the result is normal HE
for alpha = 0 the result is original image
So im supposed to vary the value of alpha by taking a reference image

Similarly there's a beta parameter to do the same in case of intesity as well.